# PHP CLI - Opening Files in Browser

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm aware that i can run php scripts straight to my windows console via `>php myscript.php`

But, i was wondering if it's at all possible for me to run a script in a similar manner, but have it open inside my browser - just like loading a web page.

In my case, using `$arguments = getopt("a:b:c:");` within the file

Then executing it in CLI like you would normally `>php myfile.php -a foo -b bar -c baz` but having the output just be the browser opening.

From all the documentation i've read, none of them seem to mention this is possible...

Comment: `php myfile.php -a foo -b bar -c baz > output.html && start output.html`

Comment: @Greg
Not what i was looking for. I want to open `myfile.php` with the inserted variables as it has styling etc.

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: Thats what i thought, it was a requirement for a project that was  given to me. I'll have to notify them.

Comment: With the same technique Greg posted, you could create a wrapper file *on the fly* which itself is a php file that initializes the variables and includes `myfile.php`. Only problem then would be to have the browser interpret the php as such and render it's output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible because php.exe comes with an built-in web server (since PHP 5.4.0+). Therefore you can run

```
http://localhost:10999/yourPHPscriptOnYourHarddrive.php
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:10999/yourPHPscriptOnYourHarddrive.php
```

In case you want to specify options, you would do it like with any other url,

```
http://127.0.0.1:10999/yourPHPscriptOnYourHarddrive.php?a=baz&b=qux
```

Here's a simple way (takes only a few minutes) how to run a PHP web server on Windows (I suppose you use Windows)

1. Download PHP (ca. 20MB): https://windows.php.net/download/
2. Put it into `c:\php\` (or wherever you like it)
3. (optional) Add `c:\php` to your PATH environment (Control Panel-> System-> Advanced System Settings-> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Path).
4. Rename `c:\php\php.ini-production` to `php.ini`
5. Start php by `c:\php\php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:10700 -t d:\`

Voila. Now you can have a PHP script locally on your hard disk in d:\foo\bar.php, and you can run/execute it by browsing with your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:10700/foo/bar.php`

(By the way, that's also for all those folks who need a replacement for QuickPHP, which isn't updated
 anymore).

Of course, you should adjust your port and your webroot, e.g. `c:\php\php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:10700 -t d:\myweb`

You can even have multiple php versions and have them run at the same time, distinguished by port, e.g.

1. `c:\php559\php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:10559 -t d:\` <-- PHP version 5.5.9
2. `c:\php70\php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:10700 -t d:\` <-- PHP version 7.0.0
3. `c:\php72\php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:10720 -t d:\` <-- PHP version 7.2.0
4. `c:\php72\php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:10999 -t d:\` <-- same PHP version but with a different port to signify that it's the newest version
5. `c:\php72b\php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:10721 -t d:\` <-- same PHP version
   but in another folder with a different php.ini configuration,
   distinguished by port.

You can verify that your PHP Servers on Windows are up and running by doing the following:

1. Create a simple .php with the content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
2. Save it as `index.php` in your webroot that you specified above, e.g. `D:\`
3. Navigate with your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:10559`, `http://127.0.0.1:10700`, `http://127.0.0.1:10720` and it will show you those different PHP versions.

If you start php from the command line, then the cmd.exe window stays open as long as the PHP webserver process is running. I have not found a way to effectively hide that command prompt aside from using "quiet.exe" (a third party tool, freeware).

To have my PHP server(s) immediately ready at Windows startup when I logon into Windows, I use a .bat batch script like this:

`quiet.exe c:\php\php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:10559 -t d:\`

**Tip:**

Once you've installed PHP on windows (even without using it as a server), you will hardly ever need to write batch (.bat) anymore. I have replaced nearly all of my batch files with .php scripts. Instead of `foo.bat`, I use `php foo.php`. All commands that are available in batch files are also available in .php.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some discussion here and some trial and error - while its possible to inject values like: `php myfile.php -a foo -b bar -c baz`

You can't then open the file in the browser with these values in it. The below works:

`php myfile.php -a foo -b bar -c baz > output.php && start output.php`

So, even though my original file had CSS styling and the like, it's still included within the output file. Which means i can also still add CLI outputs if neccesary.

The only problem would be that i dont think the results of the output could be paginated. Someone correct me if im wrong.